# awk How pass parameters to the function, called from inside awk

Tags: bash, awk

Sample function:

```
$ testfn() { echo "${1} world"; }
$ testfn hello
hello world
```

awk example:

```
$ echo "something bla bla2"|awk '$1 ~/something/ { print $0; }'
something bla bla2
```

Now I want to change "something" to "something world" using created above function, when printing it as a whole line, by passing first awk " column element" as a parameter:

```
$ echo "something bla bla2"|awk '$1 ~/something/ { $1="'"$(testfn) $1"'" ; print $0 }'
 world  bla bla2
```

^^ Above doesn't work

**Is there any way to pass parameters from awk to the function inside awk ?**

Comment: The awk example in the 2nd block only prints "something bla bla2", it doesn't print the first line of "something". Is that a typo or is it something else? What OS is this and what version of awk/gawk are you using?

Comment: typo, corrected it. it's RHEL5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you can't call shell functions from inside of `awk`. It's not a shell. However, a common workaround involves adding your function to a file and calling it using awk's `system()` function. Here's a simple example:

Contents of `yourfunction.sh`:

```
{
    echo "$1 world"
}
```

Then run:

```
echo "what the ..." | awk '{ system("./yourfunction.sh" FS $1) }'
```

Results:

```
what world
```

Note that if you find yourself having to do this, there's almost certainly a better approach. What are you *actually* trying to do here?

---

*EDIT:*

In response to the comments below, use the `getline()` function:

```
echo "what the ..." | awk '{ "./yourfunction.sh" FS $1 | getline $1 }1'
```

Results:

```
what world the ...
```

Here's some info re the `getline()` function:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html

Comment: Thank you! If I will not find another ways to achieve what I want, I'll have to try this workaround.

Comment: Hey, but this executes the function and displaying the output, what I'm trying to achieve is to replace fist element and then print the whole modified line. $ echo "what the ..." | awk '{ $1=system("./yourfunction.sh" FS $1); print; }'
what world
0 the ...;  I'm expecting result here as one line: "what world the ..."

Comment: If you're considering using getline, make sure you read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and fully understand what you're getting yourself into.

Answer (score 2):

Highly unrecommended but:

```
$ cat .env
testfn() { echo "${1} world"; }
$ echo $BASH_ENV
.env
$ echo "something bla bla2" | awk '$1 ~/something/{"bash -c \"testfn " $1 "\"" | getline $1; print $0}'
something world bla bla2
```

Now, tell us what you're really trying to do and we can help you write a sane script to do that.

Comment: Did everything as you've described. But getting errors:

BASH_ENV=.env
$ echo "something bla bla2" | awk '$1 ~/something/{"bash -c \"testfn " $1 "\"" | getline $1; print $0}'
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
something bla bla2


I'm sending a table of values to awk. What I want is to replace one field in a 5th column, based on element in 1st column, and this element should be processed via complex function (based on SQL query result from database).

Comment: Maybe your shell isn't bash and/or bash isn't available on your box? Just use whatever shell you normally use and save your function in whatever file your shell executes when a new non-login shell is started. You shouldn't do this anyway though. Unfortunately your explanation doesn't contain nearly enough information to help you write a script. If you'd like help, edit your question with sample input/output and a description of what your function should do.